# Refresh a page automatically from the Browser console

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have never really used the browser console before, so I don't really know what it is capable of doing. **How do I force/initiate an automatic refresh on a page from the browser console?** (That is, instead of having to press F5 everytime.)

Also, does the console take jQuery? Or does it depend on whether the web page you are on uses jQuery or not?

Comment: Use Opera. You can set a custom reload interval for any page (in the context menu), and load jQuery in the current tab by typing `// jquery()` in the console (yes you can't use it if it's not loaded).

Comment: Run `setInterval(() => { location.reload() }, 1000 * 60)` to refresh every 60 seconds. You can't just pass the `location.reload` function to `setInterval` for it to run directly because `reload` internally uses the `this` keyword to refer to `location`. You can fix this by passing `location.reload.bind(location)`.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You can refresh a page from within the browser console by running the following command:

```
location.reload()
```

If the website you are on has jQuery loaded you will be able to run jQuery commands.

If the website does not have jQuery loaded you can use the following bookmark to inject jQuery into the page:

```
javascript:(function(e,a,g,h,f,c,b,d){if(!(f=e.jQuery)||g>f.fn.jquery||h(f)){c=a.createElement("script");c.type="text/javascript";c.src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/"+g+"/jquery.min.js";c.onload=c.onreadystatechange=function(){if(!b&&(!(d=this.readyState)||d=="loaded"||d=="complete")){h((f=e.jQuery).noConflict(1),b=1);f(c).remove()}};a.documentElement.childNodes[0].appendChild(c)}})(window,document,"1.3.2",function($,L){(function(){var d=document.createElement("div"),c=document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0],e=false,g="";d.style.position="fixed";d.style.height="32px";d.style.width="220px";d.style.marginLeft="-110px";d.style.top="0";d.style.left="50%";d.style.padding="5px 10px";d.style.zIndex=1001;d.style.fontSize="12px";d.style.color="#222";d.style.backgroundColor="#f99";if(typeof jQuery!="undefined"){g="This page already using jQuery v"+jQuery.fn.jquery;return f()}else{if(typeof $=="function"){e=true}}function a(i,k){var h=document.createElement("script");h.src=i;var j=document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0],b=false;h.onload=h.onreadystatechange=function(){if(!b&&(!this.readyState||this.readyState=="loaded"||this.readyState=="complete")){b=true;k();h.onload=h.onreadystatechange=null;j.removeChild(h)}};j.appendChild(h)}a("http://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js",function(){if(typeof jQuery=="undefined"){g="Sorry, but jQuery wasn't able to load"}else{g="This page is now jQuerified with v"+jQuery.fn.jquery;if(e){g+=" and noConflict(). Use $jq(), not $()."}}return f()});function f(){d.innerHTML=g;c.appendChild(d);window.setTimeout(function(){if(typeof jQuery=="undefined"){c.removeChild(d)}else{jQuery(d).fadeOut("slow",function(){jQuery(this).remove()});if(e){$jq=jQuery.noConflict()}}},2500)}})();});
```

Comment: cool thank you! But what if I want to reload the page automatically say using a 10 minute interval?

Comment: Everytime you run the code and the browser refreshes, the code is wiped...anyway you can create a loop so that the code keeps on executing without you having to type it everytime...in the browser? Note, I do not have access to the source files to add code to do this...I want to do it from the browser...thx

Answer (score 25):

Use a browser tab "A" to open and control another browser tab "B". This allows you to continuously auto-reload a Web page in tab "B" that otherwise you have no control over. Your reload command from tab "A" will not be wiped out when tab "B" is reloaded.

I use this to refresh a Website so that it does not time out and log me out. This approach does not require jQuery, and does not require you to have any control over the target Web page HTML code.

Open a browser new tab "A", press F12, select Console. Type in something like this:

```
win1 = window.open("https://www.example.com");

timer1 = setInterval(function(){win1.location.href="https://www.example.com"},10*60*1000);
```

The "win1" is to assign a Javascript variable name to the new browser tab "B", so that you can have Javascript control over it. The "timer1" is also to assign a variable name for good practice and for later control. The setInterVal function runs an anonymous function to call "win1" or tab "B" to refresh it's "location.href", every 10 minutes.

You'll probably have to keep both tabs open. "Pin" them for easy access. Close both tabs to stop the auto-reload. Hard refresh of tab "A" may also stop the auto reload. You might also be able to use the variable "timer1" to cancel the auto reload.

Answer (score 5):

If you want to use the console just type `document.location.reload()` in the console. But if you want to make it automatically - it needs to be in your code.

And yes, the console will take jquery if you have included the library in your code.

One more thing: for automatic refresh you need something like

`setInterval(function(){ document.location.reload() },10*60*1000);`
But it not gonna work in the console, because after the first refresh this code won't be in the console anymore. Just place it in your code.

Comment: Is there Any way you can make it run automatically...loop? Without you having to execute the code everytime?

Answer (score 3):

You can use like

```
   document.location.reload()
```

Comment: thank you, but I was actually referring to a page that is not my page...I am monitoring a webpage that i need to check every few minutes few minutes and I don't want to press F5 everytime

Answer (score 1):

If your webpage includes jQuery. then jQuery will be avaliable in the console:)
To refresh you can type directly in console:

```
window.location.reload()
```

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way is to you use a plugin. 
"Super auto refresh" for example. Available for most of the browsers

Answer (score 0):

Saeng answer above is spot on! Works great.

If you don't want to navigate to the console to run this then wrapped it in a  tag, save it to an html file on your computer and bookmarked it. I also have it opening multiple tabs. (If I could get them showing in a split tab, I'd practically have a dashboard!)

I was looking for something that doesn't rely on a browser addon. Don't use a browser addon unless you can write it yourself. (You probably wouldn't be looking here if you could.)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

Adding to @saeng's answer, in case you need to stop the interval after a certain period of time.

Open the console and write the below-mentioned snippet.

```
INTERVAL = 5    // seconds
STOP_AFTER = 15 // seconds

// Open the same link in the new tab
win1 = window.open(location.href);

// At every 5 seconds, reload the page
timer1 = setInterval(() => {
    win1.location.reload();
    console.log("Refreshed");
},INTERVAL*1000)

// Stop reloading after 15 seconds
setTimeout(() => clearInterval(timer1), STOP_AFTER*1000)
```

It will open a new tab with the same link and reload it at some interval. After a certain period of time, it will stop reloading.

Comment: Your code answers the wrong question. He did not ask how to open the same page in a new window, he asked how to refresh the page. The correct answer has been given below.

Comment: @CharlesDPantoga, I believe my approach is an alternative option if someone else is looking for multiple options.  I agree that it is not 100% accurate to the person who asked this, but I am sure it can give insights to the person who asked the question or even anyone else looking for options.

Answer (score -2):

Add this javascript

```
setTimeout(function () { location.reload(1); }, 5000);
```

Add this below meta tag to your page

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="5; URL=http://mywebsite/mypage.aspx">
```

Many Thanks
ann